# Does 2010年10-12 means October to December of 2010, or October 12th, 2010?

Tags: meaning, calendar

I want to know whether 2010年10-12 indicates a range or an specific date.

Comment: Would you show the context? It looks more like from Oct to Dec.

Comment: The specific date would be 2010年10月12日 or 2010年10月12号

Comment: It can mean anything since it isn't written in a proper format that people would understand. Unless more context is provided, I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case it would be saying 10th month through 12th month

See @Ming's comment about the specific date format.

There could be a case where the writer is using their own unique format, but that would depend on context

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it means 9/2010-12/2010, unless in specific text it has some other meanings.